# Alternatives to StarCluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, alternate, starcluster

StarCluster is a well known toolkit for Amazon EC2. However, it was developed based on Python 2, which is going out if date. And it is not compatible with Python 3.x.

So I'd like to know **is there any alternative to StarCluster**? I have searched in stackoverflow but found no answers. Does anyone know?
I am looking forward to your advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend taking a look at [cfncluster](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/cfncluster/), which is a python tool for managing HPC clusters on AWS. It shares much of the functionality of StarCluster, and in particular uses SGE out of the box. It seems to be actively developed, at least at the time of writing, and has (experimental) [support for Python 3](https://github.com/awslabs/cfncluster/issues/157).